Overlaying openMP onto MPI program causes slow down of the region parallelised with openMP
I have a particle simulation in C which is split over 4 MPI processes and running fast (compared to serial). However, one region of my implementation is N^2 complexity, where I need to compare each particle against every other particle in that process plus 'border' particles shared from other processes. My plan to speed it up was to parallelize the outer loop with #pragma omp parallel for but every variation of OpenMP pragmas I have tried has resulted in severe slow down of my simulation, due to the nested loop in question taking significantly longer.
I have tried using schedule and reduction when starting the parallel region which didn't do much. I have also tried with 8 or 4 threads, which also didn't help. Plus a range of system sizes (to check if the speedup 'kicked in' once the overhead was worth it - it has not) and compiler optimizations.
Timing reveals that one of my four MPI processes is taking a very long time through this section which is slowing down the whole simulation as they need to wait at the end of each time-step before going to the next. The work is quite evenly distributed so none of the processes should take longer.
Code snippet (roughly copied, but have made some aspects pseudo as their details are unimportant):
double calc_1 = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) private(distances, particle_one)
for (int p = 0; p < myNumParticles; p = p + 2){
    //Particle* particle_iter = &particles[0];
    // printf("p%d: I am thread %d\n", my_rank, omp_get_thread_num());
    // fflush(stdout);
    double force_x = 0;
    double force_y = 0;
    particle_one[0] = positions[p];
    particle_one[1] = positions[p+1];
    //#pragma omp parallel shared(force_x, force_y)
    // {
    if (particle_one real){
        // for (int i = 0; i < (myNumParticles-8); i = i + 8){   
        //#pragma omp parallel for private(distances)
        for (int i = 0; i < myNumParticles; i += 2){
            if (i != p){
                // lj_counter2++;
                particle_two[0] = positions[i];
                particle_two[1] = positions[i+1];
                if (particle within distance cutoff){
                    force_function(); // modifies forces array
                    force_x += (forces[0]);
                    force_y += (forces[1]);
                } 
                distances[0] = 0;
                distances[1] = 0;
            }
        }
        // repeat conparison against border particles
        for (int j = 0; j < (num_particles_local); j += 2){
            particle_three[0] = myBorderParticles[j];
            particle_three[1] = myBorderParticles[j+1];
            if (particle is real){
                if (within distance cutoff) {
                    force_function(); // modifies forces array
                    force_x += (forces[0]);
                    force_y += (forces[1]);
                } 
                distances[0] = 0;
                distances[1] = 0;
            } else {
                // if particle with position {0, 0} found, you're at the end
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    accelerations[p] = force_x;
    accelerations[p+1] = force_y;
}
double calc_2 = omp_get_wtime();
calc_time += (calc_2-calc_1);

Timing results for a 3600 particle system:

MPI only:
373.6 seconds (of which 332.47-349.08 is spent in the above nested loop)

MPI plus openMP:
1606.2 seconds (of which 583.09-1579.96 is spent in the nested loop, depending on the process)


Further timing down below for some smaller systems:



Particles
MPI
MPI + opemMP




225
27
30


400
37
33


625
60
101


900
99
293


1225
153
490


1600
239
735



I am running it across 4 nodes with 28+ cores each and I'm not requesting an unreasonable amount of memory. It is batched with Slurm and run with mpiexec -n 4 ./executable num_particles box_size > slurms/output.txt.

There is almost certainly something wrong with the core binding of threads. 1. try and include --cpus-per-task=… in your sbatch script. 2. Instead of explicit num_threads() in the pragma, run OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK mpiexec -n $SLURM_NTASKS

Thanks @Homer512. Sorry I did not include that detail, but my slurm script does have cpus-per-task set to 4 and I have manually printed/checked that all the threads are created with printf("thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num()); fflush(stdout)

Which MPI/OpenMP implementation do you use? For the Intel ones, you can set KMP_AFFINITY to verbose so to see the binding. AFAIK some MPI implementation properly bind OMP threads, some badly do it (depending on the target platform) and some don't. Binding issues are very common. In such case a schedule(guided) or schedule(dynamic,X) (where X is the granularity) can behave better than the default static scheduling. On platforms with multiple NUMA nodes, this can be significantly worst.

Note that the mapping of threads to cores also matters. If threads are map to cores using a spread policy, then you might use only one NUMA node over N. This can significantly slow down memory operations. The best thing to do to check such issue is to profile the code on 1 NUMA node first (and check cores of other NUMA node are not working showing some bad mapping). Personally, I saw so many mapping issue/bugs that I tend to manually map each thread to each core using mapping script (tedious to write but really great to reuse).

@JérômeRichard I am running on a cluster I don't own so I am a bit limited with what I can do, but I believe I am using openmpi-x86_64 and openMP 3.1 (it's just dated to July 2011). I have tried implementing a dynamic schedule but it only shaved about 6% off of the runtime.

The mapping of threads to cores makes sense. The cluster is a bit backed up but I will attempt to batch a run on one node and see if that changes anything. How do you go about manually mapping them? I am very new to HPC so I haven't heard of this before.

there are some fishy thing with your snippet. particle_two and particle_three are set but never used. They should at least be declared private. Setting accelerations[p+1 looks suspicious too. Are you sure you did not want to set accelerations[2*p] and accelerations[2*p+1]? or accelerations[p] and accelerations[p+MyNumParticles]?

printf(… omp_get_thread_num()) doesn't tell you anything. But you may want to print the results of sched_getaffinity() and compare on which CPUs the threads are allowed to run. Regarding the potentially fishy code parts: If you run the code on a normal machine without MPI, does it accelerate with more threads or also become slower?

Where does the forces array come from. Is this a global variable? Since it doesn't show up in the code at all, I assume it's shared and you have a data race. I suggest that you run data race detection with a single MPI process first, then with multiple MPI processes. You can use clang, aocc, cray or latest Intel compiler: https://hpc-wiki.info/hpc/Archer

Similar:distances, particle_two and particle_three are shared.

as a side note, it is a good practice to add a default(none) clause in each OpenMP section since it can help preventing some bugs.

@GillesGouaillardet the for loop iterates on p with step 2, so accelerate[p+1] seems to be fine. Using a struct {x,y} would improve readability and avoid such confusion.

The question regarding MPI/openmp implementation is: which version of openmpi (3/4/5? See mpiexec --version) and what c compiler and version (usually mpicc --version) do you use?

Sorry for the overlook. Indeed, we need the slurm script and the MPI library information. The OP claims there is one job per node, so the worst case scenario should be OpenMP threads ending up time sharing, leading to a small overhead. The fact the slowdown is massive suggests more than one MPI task is running on a given node (and binding is suboptimal) and/or the OpenMPization of the code is incorrect.

one MPI task per node.

Note that "openMP 3.1" does not provide much information about the implementation. The implementation is generally defined by the compiler (eg. GOMP for GCC, IOMP/KOMP for Intel/Clang compilers).

A small improvement for the dynamic scheduling (using a good granularity) suggests that there is no competition for the same resource unless the scheduling is already fair (so the binding would be balanced). This is not a strong evidence so it does not help much (as opposed to having a sharp performance difference).
